# How to disable angular-ui bootstrap tabs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a multi step form in angularjs and angularjs bootstrap.

I have the following html code, buttons on each step that validate current tab and move to the next. What I'm looking for is a "disabled" state for each tab that will be set to true while the form is not validated in current state "isStepClean(0)".

I've tried with class="disabled" and disabled as attribute but didn't work. Any ideas how to do it?

```
<tabs>
    <pane heading="1. Recipients" active="panes[0].active" disabled="panes[0].disabled">
        ....
        <input type="button" ng-disabled="isStepClean(0)" class="btn btn-info pull-right" ng-click="panes[1].active = true" name="" value="Next step" />
    </pane>
    <pane heading="2. Information" active="panes[1].active" disabled="panes[1].disabled">
         ....
         <input type="button" ng-disabled="isStepClean(1)" class="btn btn-info pull-right" ng-click="panes[2].active = true" name="" value="Next step" />
    </pane>
    <pane heading="3. Preview" active="panes[2].active" disabled="panes[2].disabled">
         ....
         <input type="button" ng-disabled="isStepClean(2)" class="btn btn-info pull-right" ng-click="panes[3].active = true" name="" value="Next step" />
    </pane>
</tabs>
```

In the controller I have:

```
$scope.panes = [
        {active:true},
        {active:false},
        {active:false},
        {active:false}
    ];
```

Answer (score 4):

Someone just informed me that this modification was made already in Angular-UI.  It's not on the broken out Angular-Bootstrap, but it is part of the bootstrap component of Angular-UI.  Hopefully they'll sync up the changes soon:

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/2b78dd16abd7e09846fa484331b5c35ece6619a2

EDIT: previous answer because it took me a while to figure out.

Currently, its not built into Angular-Bootstrap, but you can modify the library like so:

Add a disabled attribute to your pane (below example is with ng-repeat, but you can add it manually as you have in your example):

```
 <tabs>
     <pane ng-repeat="pane in panes" heading="{{pane.title}}" disabled="{{pane.disabled}}" active="pane.active">{{pane.content}}</pane>
 </tabs>
```

Then make the following modifications to your `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` file if using `ui-bootstrap.js` I assume you'll know how to modify these instructions for external templates):

Search `$templateCache.put("template/tabs/tabs.html"...` and add the `disabled:pane.disabled` property to `ng-class` (with proper escaping):

```
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected, disabled:pane.disabled}">
      <a ng-click="select(pane)" href="">{{pane.heading}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

Search for `.directive('pane', ['$parse', function($parse) {` and change:

```
scope:{
  heading:'@'
},
```

to:

```
scope:{
  heading:'@',
  disabled:'@'
},
```

Test it out by adding disabled to the panes array:

```
$scope.panes = [
        {active:true},
        {active:false, disabled:true},
        {active:false, disabled:true},
        {active:false}
    ];
```

Now use your validation function (e.g., `isStepClean()`) to set disabled on the panes array.

Note: this will only apply `disabled` class to the `li` elements (i.e., this will cosmetically change your `li` elements to comfort to the `disabled` class in Twitter Bootstrap).  You can add whatever disabling behavior you want as a custom directive.

Comment: $scope.panes array should be set in controller?

Comment: Hey @MAJOJ, sorry didn't see this question. But yes. :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using angular-ui tabset, the use of *disabled* is deprecated. You should use **disable** instead.

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading='Tab Title' disable="hasErrors">
        ...
```

Comment: Worked for me. I'm using Angular-UI Bootsrap v1.33: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1):

A checkbox added to disable the tab using scope.

If checkbox is true then a function is been triggered, which assigns the value of scope to class attribute {{btnClass}}. By conditional statement in data-toggle we can set this attribute.

**data-toggle="{{btnClass == 'disabled' ? '' : 'tab'}}"**

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.target[isselected]" name="" ng-click="checkbox(isselected)"> TARGET ALL USERS



    <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left" role="tablist">
  <span class="navTitle">TARGET GROUP</span><!-- 'tabs-right' for right tabs -->
    <li class="active" role="presentation"><a href='' data-target="#everyone" aria-controls="everyone" data-toggle="tab">EVERYONE</a></li>
<li class="{{btnClass}}"><a href='' data-target="#userprofile" aria-controls="userprofile" data-toggle="{{btnClass == 'disabled' ? '' : 'tab'}}">USER PROFILE</a></li>
<li class="{{btnClass}}"><a href='' data-target="#customergroup" aria-controls="customergroup" data-toggle="{{btnClass == 'disabled' ? '' : 'tab'}}">CUSTOMER GROUP</a></li>
<li class="{{btnClass}}"><a href='' data-target="#customer" aria-controls="customer" data-toggle="{{btnClass == 'disabled' ? '' : 'tab'}}">CUSTOMER</a></li>
<li class="{{btnClass}}"><a href='' data-target="#catalog" aria-controls="catalog" data-toggle="{{btnClass == 'disabled' ? '' : 'tab'}}">CATALOG</a></li>
<li class="{{btnClass}}"><a href='' data-target="#customerwarehouse" aria-controls="customerwarehouse" data-toggle="{{btnClass == 'disabled' ? '' : 'tab'}}">CUSTOMER WAREHOUSE</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Angularjs

```
$scope.checkbox = function(isselected) {
if (vm.target[isselected]) {
$scope.btnClass = "disabled";
}
else {
  $scope.btnClass = "";
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two tabs with identical title, one with `ng-hide="yourDisableCondition"`, the other (which needs no content) with `ng-show="yourDisableCondition"` AND `disabled="true"`.